# Shared albums from Google Plus not showing in Google Photos

Tags: google-plus, google-photos

Last year I made a few albums and shared them. I think I used the Google Plus photo feature to create a link and email it to my family. Now I'm using Google Photos (i.e. the new standalone app) and I can still see my albums under "Collections".

My question is: why don't they *also* appear under my "Shared albums" tab in Google Photos? The albums are marked as shared in the "Collections" tab, but only new albums that I share using the Google Photos app end up under "Shared albums". Do I have to “re-share” all the old shared albums to make them list properly? Will it affect the existing links my family currently uses to view them?

The documentation from Google is very poor on this subject btw.

Note: the same also applies to albums shared to me, i.e. a different owner. After receiving a link I can only see newly shared albums in Google Photos, not older shared albums (I have to go to Google Plus in classic mode to view them since I lost the old links).

Answer (score -1):

I think recent update Google has split Google+ and Google+ Photos. Google+ Photos turn into Google Photo, which means they have different sharable system. Google+ Photos can still be found from the old style Google+ photos page like https://plus.google.com/u/0/+YouTube/photos. But you have to found your shared album first. Old Google+ Photos can only shared to Google+ Users. So, your friend must need a Google+ account to check your shared albums.

Now Google+ is redesigning and has a brand new look. I don't know what will happen after Google+ turn into new design. But now I can answer your question. You don't need to share your album again. Your friend can check all your shared photos from your profile photo page. And you can also check theirs.

Comment: All the info in your answer was already mentioned in my question. My question was how do I get the old shared photos to appear in the new Google+ Photos, under the shared tab.